# How can i rewrite these JavaScript promises to be less complicated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I wrote this, but it looks rough, its for node js so all values need to be gotten in order

```
import tripfind from '../model/tripfind';
import addbook from '../model/addbook';
import bookfind from '../model/bookfind';

function addBook(info) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let rowcount = -1;
    bookfind(0, -1, -1).then((result) => {
      if (result) {
        rowcount = result.rowCount;
      } else {
        rowcount = 0;
      }
      tripfind(info.trip_id, 0).then((xresult) => {
        let val = '';
        if (xresult === 'false') {
          val = 'trip is not valid';
          resolve(val);
        } else {
          addbook(info, rowcount).then((value) => {
            if (value === 'invalid id') {
              resolve('invalid id');
            }
            resolve(value);
          }).catch((err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
          });
        }
      }).catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
}

export default addBook;
```

thats the code above, the code also gets exported and is handled as a promise function, please help if you can

Comment: Just return the values, and delete all of the catch callbacks. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/34397

Comment: You're missing some `return`s... can be written more crealy in async await approach.. i'll write an exmple

Comment: Use modern `async/await` pattern

Comment: [codereview.se] is the more appropriate place to ask about improving code style.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some `return`s of promises, and if you like this way of writing you should indent `then()` and `catch()` in the same way. Also doing this

```
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
```

is useless, caus you catch an error to reject it. Rewritten in `promise` pattern (and a bit of optimization):

```
function addBook(info) {

    return bookfind(0, -1, -1)
      .then((result) => {
        rowcount = result ? result.rowCount : 0

        return tripfind(info.trip_id, 0)
          .then((xresult) => {
            if (xresult === 'false') {
              return 'trip is not valid'
            }

            return addbook(info, rowcount)
          })
      })
}
```

Anyway is more clear with the async/await pattern:

```
async function addBook(info) {

  let result = await bookfind(0, -1, -1)

  rowcount = result ? result.rowCount : 0

  let xresult = await tripfind(info.trip_id, 0)
  if (xresult === 'false')
    return 'trip is not valid'

  let value = await addbook(info, rowcount)
  return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `async` / `await`, this example is functionally equivalent to what you had before:

```
function addBook (info) {
  return bookfind(0, -1, -1).then(result => {
    const { rowCount } = result || { rowCount: 0 };

    return tripfind(info.trip_id, 0).then(trip =>
      trip === 'false'
      ? 'trip is not valid'
      : addbook(info, rowCount)
    );
  });
}
```

Sections like

```
.then((value) => {
  if (value === 'invalid id') {
    resolve('invalid id');
  }
  resolve(value);
})
```

```
.catch((err) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  }
});
```

```
.catch((error) => {
  reject(error);
});
```

are completely superfluous, so removing them doesn't affect the logic at all. After removing those, and unwrapping your `Promise` constructor antipattern, you can see the logic becomes a lot more simplified.

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
function addBook(info) {
  return bookfind(0, -1, -1).then((result) => tripfind(info.trip_id, 0)
    .then((xresult) => (xresult === 'false') ? 
      'trip is not valid' : 
      addbook(info, result ? result.rowCount : 0)
    )
  );
}
```

or with `async/await`

```
async function addBook(info) {
  const result = await bookfind(0, -1, -1);

  const xresult = await tripfind(info.trip_id, 0)

  return xresult === "false"? 
    'trip is not valid' : 
    addbook(info, result ? result.rowCount : 0);
}
```

Avoid the Promise/Deferred antipattern: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

and remove pointless/useless code, like this function for example:

```
(value) => {
  if (value === 'invalid id') {
    resolve('invalid id');
  }
  resolve(value);
}
```

which always resolves to `value`. that's like `return value === 1? 1: value`

Or all the `(error) => { reject(error); }` just to "forward" the error to the returned promise.

or this construct

```
let rowcount = -1;

//....

  if (result) {
    rowcount = result.rowCount;
  } else {
    rowcount = 0;
  }

//....

doSomethingWith(rowcount)
```

which can be summed up as `doSomethingWith(result ? result.rowCount : 0)`

Comment: I particularly like how you moved the `result ? result.rowCount : 0` expression to the parameter list.

Comment: Whoops, my dyslexia is running riot today.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people might tell you that `async`/`await` will solve this better. I think the problem is more about how the promises are used. If you have access to change the functions you are calling here's what I'd recommend.

1. Have functions return things of the same shape - e.g., the call to `bookfind` can return a rejected promise or a resolved promise that wraps `undefined` or `{..., :rowcount:12}`. If we remove the `undefined` result and return a default `{..., rowcount:0 }` it would simplify the calling functions substantially and contain logic a bit better.
2. Remove the superfluous function calls (`.catch`s and the `addbook` `.then` bit)

Here's what those functions could look like (not knowing your setup at all)

```
function tripfind(id, num) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    doSomething(function(err, results) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (results === "false") return reject(new Error("trip is not valid"));
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
}

function bookfind(id, start, end /*or whatever*/) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    findBooks(function(err, results) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      // handle odd cases too
      if (!results) return resolve({ rowcount: 0 });
      return resolve(results);
    });
  });
}
```

and the usages

```
bookfind(0, -1, -1).then(results =>{}).catch(err=>{})
tripfind(id, 0).then(results =>{}).catch(err=>{})
```

Using Promises this way, we don't have to check the value of `results` because if it wasn't there, the promise shouldn't resolve. Likewise, the shape of the thing coming out of the promise should always be the same. (I call it a smell when a function returns `String|Object|Undefined`, it's possible but I'd look hard at it first)

Using this pattern and removing calls that don't do anything (all the `.catch` calls), we can simplify the code down to:

```
function addBook(info) {
  return bookfind(0, -1, -1).then(({ rowcount }) =>
    tripfind(info.trip_id, 0).then(() =>
      addbook(info, rowcount)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Based on your philosophy, shouldn't the inner-most return value be `result === "false" ? Promise.reject(new Error("trip is not valid")) : addbook(info, rowcount)`?

Comment: I was trying to balance how much to rewrite with making a point. Your answer had the straightforward rewrite so i was trying to provide something else. In this case, I'd put the false checking in the `tripfind` function.

Comment: That's a fair point. I wasn't attempting to debunk your answer, just making sure I didn't misunderstand anything. I appreciate you integrating my feedback into your answer though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I did in fact update the answer. ;)